# Java - Openjpa: how to specify sequence generator starting from hibernate hbm

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I've to switch persistence of a project using **HIBERNATE** to **OPENJPA** and I started from  entities and hbm files which define type of columns, etc. 
I've an Id on hibernate generated in this way:

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">seq_illness</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
```

how can I "translate" it ointo Jpa annotation to my entity class, in particular how can I represent sequence generator? 
I'm new to this feature and I don't understand well usage of

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

how can I reproduce sequence parameter and define the correct sequence generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JPA, the mapping for this column would look like:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="ID_GEN" sequenceName="NAME_OF_SEQ_IN_DB")
@GeneratedValue(generator="ID_GEN")
private Integer id;
```

See the following documentation for further information:

[@SequenceGenerator](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SequenceGenerator)

[@GeneratedValue](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GeneratedValue)